# How to use navigation-rule

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have an issue with using properly the navigation use

This is my main jsf:

```
<ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="mainForm" prependId="false">
                    <ui:include src="home_page.xhtml"/>
            </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

home_page jsf:

```
<h:form id="jh" prependId="false">
    <p:commandButton id="myb" action="failure" value="te" />
</h:form>
```

web xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/main.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and faces-config xml:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>failure</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/core.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Any idea what I am missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: Whats the problem ? What is not working ??

Comment: the problem is that it’s not navigate to core.xhml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing the form solve the problem.

```
  <h:form id="jh" prependId="false"> solve the problem.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to web.xml smth similar to this (with correct relative path to faces-config.xml):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```